# Video not played on some Android devices

Tags: android, video, screen-resolution

I have an android application, in which I need to play a video at startup. I have tried different combinations of video sizes but a video of size 800x 1280 fails to play on most of the devices except a few like Samsung 10" tablet. I tried playing the same video with reduced size and it works. So it may not be encoding issue.

P.S. This is not a streaming video. The video is stored in raw resources folder of project.

What could be the reason that android fails to play the video of the size 800x1280? Is it related to hardware limitations of the devices?

Comment: Are you trying to play your video using VideoView in your activity or using Android default player?

Comment: I tried using video view in activity as well as using Android default player. Both produce same results.

Answer (score 1):

> I think your video formate was .mpeg,or mp4,.3gp and andorid device is
>   supported in H.264 video you must encode to H.264 ...formate i think
>   it will help you.

Comment: The video is H.264 video. It works if its size is 480x800 with same settings. It fails for this size.

Answer (score 1):

1280x800 is beyond 720p HD resolution.  Usually decoders that support only 720p HD will support upto 1280x720. Some of the decoders will not be designed to support 720x1280 but will support 1280x720 though that should be rare and you should get 720x1280 playing if the device is 720p capable. You need to ensure you have beyond 720p support for the device you are trying which is rare for older phones unless they were high end smartphones at their release time.